# Reading defining line of text file in java

Tags: java, android, text-files

I am trying to develop application for android . how I can get the defining line of textfile ? 
For instance  I have to read 15. line of textfile. how I can do that?

Comment: Other than the 'android' tag this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/in-java-how-to-read-from-a-file-a-specific-line-given-the-line-number

Comment: Agreed.  And the other question is more intelligible.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know each line has the same length, the only way is to read each line until you get to the 15th.  You can't skip to a specific line unless you have a way to calculate its offset, or maintain some sort of index file.