# How to read a file from a certain offset in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

Hey I'm trying to open a file and read just from an offset for a certain length! 
I read this topic:
[How to read a specific line using the specific line number from a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/in-java-how-to-read-from-a-file-a-specific-line-given-the-line-number)
in there it said that it's not to possible read a certain line without reading the lines before, but I'm wondering about bytes!

```
FileReader location = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(location);
// Read from bytes 1000 to 2000
// Something like this
inputFile.read(1000,2000);
```

Is it possible to read certain bytes from a known offset?

Comment: Read up on [reading files using Java.](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/io.html) `Seek` methods exist.

Comment: Did you manage to implement the suggested solutions? I'm trying to do the same, but having a really hard time.

Comment: Hi @kryzystof , Yes I managed this back then with RandomAccessFile class (the accepted answer). Unfortunately I don't have access to the code any more since its been 9 years

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) exposes a function:

```
seek(long pos) 
          Sets the file-pointer offset, measured from the beginning of this file, at which the next read or write occurs.
```

Comment: Is this thing fast or it just go through the previous ones also?

Comment: I would imagine it is fast, since you are just referencing the pointer.  IIRC a jump table of sorts is created and it should be O(1) time.

Comment: Technically it should jump directly, since the bytes of a single file are contiguous on disk.

Comment: @Tudor I thought that there was no guarantee, granted the last time I read anything about how the system writes to the disk was about 3 years ago.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Indeed, if the disk is heavily fragmented you may have files split in several places, but normally they should be contiguous.

Comment: Yeah But My file is right i want and is not going to change so it work ok for me!

Answer (score 18):

**`FileInputStream.getChannel().position(123)`**

This is another possibility in addition to `RandomAccessFile`:

```
File f = File.createTempFile("aaa", null);
byte[] out = new byte[]{0, 1, 2};

FileOutputStream o = new FileOutputStream(f);
o.write(out);
o.close();

FileInputStream i = new FileInputStream(f);
i.getChannel().position(1);
assert i.read() == out[1];
i.close();
f.delete();
```

This should be OK since the docs for [`FileInputStream#getChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#getChannel%28%29) say that:

> Changing the channel's position, either explicitly or by reading, will change this stream's file position.

I don't know how this method compares to `RandomAccessFile` however.

Comment: This seems like a more flexible solution than the `RandomAccessFile`, because it allows you to return the `InputStream` to be processed outside of your method. In case of the RAF, if you wanted to do that, you would not be able to close the RAF, thus having a resource leak. Unless I misunderstood something.