# Java Fixed File Size operation

Tags: java

In Java using `RandomAccessFile` I can create a file and then do `setLength`
Now Assume I allocate length of `1024 bytes`. Now I wrote say `512 bytes`. 
Now again I want to write `256 bytes` without changing size of the file and clearing those `512 bytes`

I do not want to use `setLength(0)` in the middle of my process to avoid `java.io.IOException: No space left on device`

Answer (score 4):

You can use seeks:

```
file.setLength(1024);
file.write(new byte[512]); //or some other 512 bytes
//close and reopen later
file.seek(512);
//write 256 more bytes
```

Edit: I don't think you're realizing the spirit of `RandomAccessFile`. You can create it to be 512 bytes and keep writing to it so it can extend implicitly without `setLength` calls.

Comment: //write 256 more bytes this is what i  want  to wipe out previously written 512 bytes and write fresh 256 bytes

Comment: @Avinash ok, seek(0) and then write.

Comment: seek(offset) sets the location in the file where the next read or write starts from.  seek(0) resets to the beginning of the file.  seek(512) moves 512 bytes into the file.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671126/how-to-read-a-file-from-a-certain-offset

Comment: seek(), read(), write(), getFilePointer(), see: http://qdaolong.blogspot.com/2013/02/offset-of-file-in-c-and-java.html