# How to set an offset with readline in java?

Tags: java, io, readline

Is there a way to read from a file via readline() and an offset in java?
For example, file.readline(10) return the 10's line of the file without reading the first 9.

Comment: I don't think so, how would it know that this line is the 10'th line if it hadn't read the first 9 ?

Comment: maybe you mean "reading 10 lines and ignoring the contents of the first 9" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readline` doesn't provide such functionality. You can use `seek` function to set an offset (link to [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671126/how-to-read-a-file-from-a-certain-offset). However, it has no way of knowing about newline symbols or anything else. It simply sets offset in bytes. If length of your lines is fixed - you can use it just like you want. Otherwise - you need to use `readline` several times to get required string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, how would it know that this line is the 10'th line if it hadn't read the first 9 ?. But you can read the file once,store it in an ArrayList or some Data Structure and than access each line alone. You can store line 1 in index ,line 2 in index 2...

Comment: the problem is that i don't want to read the whole file because it is very big.
i think the best solution for my problem is editing the file, so that every line has the same size. then i can set the line with the read bytes method.