# How to read csv file from specific line number upto provided line number?

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file and suppose I want to read file
from line number say 14 till line number 30
How this can be achieved?

Thanks,

Comment: Read it like how you read an excel file

Comment: Have you even google it ?. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/in-java-how-to-read-from-a-file-a-specific-line-given-the-line-number

Comment: Yes,I have google it but not find any specific answers

Comment: interesting. just wrote a stateful csv parser that could do that. well in c# that is

Comment: CSVReader can be used for reading a CSV file starting from some line. The fourth argument of CSVReader can be used to skip lines, so if you want to start processing the CSV file from the nth line, you can pass (n-1) as the last argument and then process it upto the required line number.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried this:

```
FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("someFile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
for(int i = 0; i < 14; ++i)
  br.readLine();
String lineIWant = br.readLine();
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but is there any approach better then this?

Answer (score 0):

Use any of CSV libraries, such as CSV Java or CSV Reader.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/

http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use jxl library. You can find it at http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/. I use it in my project and it is really helpful.