# How to extract specific line from a text file without sequentially travelling over lines

Tags: java, file, io

I want to read a specific line in a text file **without sequentially** going over each line and maintaining a line-counter or something.

Basically I want to know if there is any Class from **core library** that will give **Random-Access** to any line in a text file.

Comment: MAy be you could check it out here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/in-java-how-to-read-from-a-file-a-specific-line-given-the-line-number

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard functionality that implements your requirements. But you might want to have a look at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

... for an alternative approach.