# flatworm reading file from line nunber

Tags: java

Is there any way to read a flat file from perticular line number? I heard about record-ident tag but not sure what to pass there.

There is no matching string, I need to read from a perticular libne number only.

Comment: Do you want to read only single line or multiple lines ?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/in-java-how-to-read-from-a-file-a-specific-line-given-the-line-number

Comment: Srinivas B. It is to read multiple lines

Comment: Read from a given line until the end or a line range? Are your lines of fixed length (note that it require that the encoding encodes with a fixed length as well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IOUtil` is the utility class for accessing flat files.

IOUtil.lineIterator(Reader reader) can be useful for reading file from line nunber

```
LineIterator it = IOUtils.lineIterator(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inputfile.txt")));
 for (int lineNoInFile = 0; it.hasNext(); lineNoInFile++) {
    String outputLine = (String) it.next();
    if (lineNoInFile == inputLineNumber) {
        return outputLine;
    }
 }
```

And to read multiple lines `IOUtils.readLines` can be used

```
int outputLinenumber = 25;      
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(new FileInputStream(new File("inputfile.txt")), "UTF-8");
for (int index = outputLinenumber; index<=lines.size();index ++){
  //Iterate the Files
}
```

It's just sample code.