# Files.lines to skip broken lines in Java8

Tags: java, file, java-8, java-stream

I am reading a very large (500mb) file with Files.lines(...).
It reads a part of the file but at some point it breaks with java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

I think the file has lines with different charsets. Is there a way to skip these broken lines? I know that the stream returned is backed by a Reader and with the reader I know how to skip, but don't know how to get the Reader from the stream to set it up as I like.

```
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("bigtest.txt").toURI()), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
        stream
            .filter(s -> s.substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("aa"))
            .forEach(lines::add);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        // catch
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can’t filter lines with invalid characters *after* the decoding when the preconfigured decoder already stops the decoding with an exception. You have to configure a `CharsetDecoder` manually to tell it to ignore invalid input or replace that input with a special character.

```
CharsetDecoder dec=StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder()
                  .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
Path path=Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("bigtest.txt").toURI());
List<String> lines;
try(Reader r=Channels.newReader(FileChannel.open(path), dec, -1);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r)) {
        lines=br.lines()
                .filter(s -> s.regionMatches(true, 0, "aa", 0, 2))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This simply ignores charset decoding errors, skipping the characters. To skip entire lines containing errors, you can let the decoder insert a replacement character (defaults to `'\ufffd'`) for errors and filter out lines containing that character:

```
CharsetDecoder dec=StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder()
                  .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
Path path=Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("bigtest.txt").toURI());
List<String> lines;
try(Reader r=Channels.newReader(FileChannel.open(path), dec, -1);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r)) {
        lines=br.lines()
                .filter(s->!s.contains(dec.replacement()))
                .filter(s -> s.regionMatches(true, 0, "aa", 0, 2))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Holger. I was also wondering if is possible to do it with the stream to avoid the boilerplate code, but it looks is not possible (the stream is backed by a Reader, I hoped it was possible to get the reader somehow and add the decoder)

Comment: That’s not supported by that API. But even if it was, it wouldn’t be more compact than the code here. Note that the “boilerplate” is only one additional line. The result looks more verbose only because I did a more generous formatting as I don’t like horizontal scrolling. Well, and I use more white-space when posting code examples for the broader audience than I do in my real code. Of course, you can inline `dec` and `path` and use `import static` for `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` as well as for `CodingErrorAction.*`, `Channels.newReader`, `FileChannel.open`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you again Holger.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, the solution is going to be complex and more bug-prone when using the Streams API. I suggest to just use a normal for-loop to read from a BufferedReader and then capture the MalformedInputException. This also enables capture of other IO exceptions to be distinguished:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(path,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
     try{
          String line = null;
          while((line=r.readLine())!=null){
               if(line.substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("aa")){
                    lines.add(line);
                }
     }catch(MalformedInputException mie){
           // ignore or do something
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have a few considerations:
* usually using functional style make code clearer and more concise. At the moment there are a few lines of code but if it grows I think functional is the way to go
* you are programming through exceptions, that is a practice I don't really like
* you lose laziness and all the benefit of it (easy parallelisation, stateless code, ...)

having saying this, your solution is definitely another working solution.

Comment: @Fra good points. The answer by Holger is more elaborate. However, mine has no loss of 'laziness' since it too is lazy. However, Stream's exceptions are complex to deal with. Looks good until you have to debug :) Also, in Holgers solution, you still need to capture and deal with an IOException. Unless you are going to ignore that entirely and pass it up. The biggest problem is that using the Stream-filter paradigm, that code is very slow. For a big file of 500 MB, I would avoid the filters.