# Java lambda, turning a text file of records (eg CSV) into a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've been playing with Java 8 lambda expressions for a month and I'm pretty happy with everything it can do. I especially like the abstraction of streams to iterate over a collection of elements more efficiently and with less code.

Now one thing I'm trying to figure out is abstracting a text file or SQL query of records into a stream of some sorts while still allowing it to be buffered. I already have tried to implement the Stream interface and got overwhelmed by the abstract methods.

I'd paste my work in progress but so far it all has fallen flat, and my research is coming up nil too. Can someone show an example of how to turn a CSV using a BufferedReader into a stream for each line? All while maintaining the buffered nature? I'd also like it to support parallel too. This way, for every record that is buffered, it can be passed to a series of higher order functions in parallel.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/nio/file/Files.java#Files.lines%28java.nio.file.Path%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s easy to convert a BufferedReader into a stream for each line, just use the method [`BufferedReader.lines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) made exactly for this purpose. Of course, you can simply use [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-), skipping the `BufferedReader` part entirely, [unless you need a specially configured `CharSetDecoder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26065463/2711488).

Then you can use `map` or `flatMap` to convert a stream of lines into a stream of records or individual cells.

Generally, it’s not a good idea to implement the entire `Stream` interface manually. The usual way of creating custom `Stream`s is to implement [`Spliterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) and create a `Stream` using the method [`StreamSupport.stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-).

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-

Though all streams support `parallel()` to at least some extent.