# Java buffered reader - jump to line

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm reading through a file like this:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    System.exit(1);
}

file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(file));
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
//do stuff for each line
}
reader.close();
```

The file looks like this:

```
0 LOAD 1,3 
1 LOAD 0,2
2 ADD 1,2
3 ADD 0,1
4 LSS 1,3,2
5 STOR 62,1
```

I've parsed it like this:

```
String[] actionFirstSplit = line.split(" ");
```

There's code associated with each line that isn't shown here. For certain lines, I'd like to jump back to a certain line number, and continue reading through the file once again. What is the best way to do this? Do I have to create another reader and skip lines until the particular line I'm interested in? I'm looking along the lines of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/how-to-read-a-specific-line-using-the-specific-line-number-from-a-file-in-java), but I want to continue reading the rest of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were my project, I'd

- Create a class, perhaps called MyClass (for discussion purposes only), to hold one line's worth of data. It would have line number, String for text (command?), and a `List<Integer>` to hold a variable number of int parameters.
- Create a `List<MyClass>` to hold a linear collection of objects of this class.
- In my single BufferedReader, read each line, create a MyClass object, and place it in the collection.
- When I needed to loop back, I simply search through my collection -- no need to re-read from a file since this is a relatively expensive task while looping through a List such as an ArrayList isn't quite so.

Comment: This looks good. If i'm understanding correctly, the reader doesn't actually read or contain the parameters, text, etc. Only a reference to the object? I'm going to try this...

Comment: @user25976: the reader just reads a line. Then you break the line into its constituent parts, create a viable object with it and add it to your List.