# How to get specific line from a txt file in java

Tags: java

I'm dumping info about all the processes running on my pc into a .txt file. To do this I execute handle.exe from my java application. The file contains all the running processes in this format:

```
RuntimeBroker.exe pid: 4756 
4: Key           HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image 
8: Event  
   10: WaitCompletionPacket 
   1C: IRTimer       
   20: WaitCompletionPacket 
   24: IRTimer       
   28: File          \Device\CNG

--

SearchIndexer.exe pid: 5616 
4: Event         
8: WaitCompletionPacket 
C: IoCompletion  
1C: IRTimer
20: File          \Device\0000007s
22: Directory
```

I need to get the name of the process that is using a given device i.e. if I'm looping through the file searching for the string "\Device\0000007s", I need to get the name of the process and the process id which is a few lines above. Does anybody know how could I do this? The processes are delimited by a line of dashes -- in the file. Bear in mind that the file is massive, this is just an example.

Comment: Does it have to be Java?  `awk` is made for this sort of thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a specific line using the specific line number from a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/how-to-read-a-specific-line-using-the-specific-line-number-from-a-file-in-java)

Comment: Yeah @cxw it needs to be Java, it's a Java application

Comment: You could simply replace out all the spaces, break on the delimiter and loop through to grep/regex the string you are looking for.  Once you have that just use String methods to pull out "pid:[0-9][0-9]+"  im just spitballing here but experiment with that.

Comment: The thing is I don't know yet the string I'm looking for, the file could be in use by any process with any process name. As if I need to go backwards into the file until the line of dashes and then one line ahead to get the process name, I'm struggling so bad

Answer (score 1):

I would read each line of a process (using a `Scanner`) into a `List<String>`. Then search through the `List<String>` for your desired `String` and if it is there, do your processing. Here is some psuedo-code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("path/to/file.txt");
List<String> stringList;
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();

  if(nextLine.equals("--") {
    for(String line : stringList) {
      if(line.contains("\Device\0000007s") {
        // Do your processsing here
      }
    }

    stringList.clear();
  }

  else {
    stringList.add(nextLine);
  }

}
```

This is just psuedo-code, doesn't handle the edge case of the last process and probably won't compile. I will leave the nitty-gritty syntax up to you.

There is probably a more optimal way of doing this, with less looping. But for simple things like this I much prefer a clear approach to an optimized one.

Comment: Nice one Adam Rosini, I'll give this a try and see if it doesn't take ages looping and finding the string as I need this to a be quite quick process. Cheers!