# How do I read only one line of text file?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline, fileinputstream, inputstreamreader

My program is reading all lines in the file but i just need the second one.

```
String line;
try (
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(source);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {  
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the second line and you are sure the file always has at least two lines, you can just read twice and ignore the first time.

```
br.readLine(); //read, but ignore
System.out.println(br.readLine()); // read and output
```

Comment: Is there a universall method to do this? I could use this method in other classes too but for lines 8-20 and to call br.readLine(); 8 times is unnecessary.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2312769/7677308

Comment: might be the right thing - thank you