# reading parts of a txt file

Tags: java

I have a text file with the following URLs:

```
http://www.google.com.uy
http://www.google.com.es
http://www.google.com.nz
```

I need to read the second line of this TXT, the second URL showed there.
I've been researching and I didn't find what I exactly need, because, although I know I have to use the `BufferedReader` class, I don't know how to specify the "line" I want to read.

This is what I wrote so far:

```
String fileread = "chlist\\GATHER.txt";
try {                                         
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileread));
    String gatherText = br.readLine();
    br.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {}
```

Comment: Keep a counter of the number of lines you read. Stop at the second one.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/in-java-how-to-read-from-a-file-a-specific-line-given-the-line-number) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138390/read-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file)

Comment: If `readLine()` read one line of text, how many call to `readLine()` do you need to read the second line of the text ?

Comment: Both current answers are covered in the accepted answer of the possible duplicate Q/A

Comment: There isn't a common way to extract a specific line from a file with Java.  You have to count your way through.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `br.readLine();` will return you a line from the text file and move you to the next line, so the second call will give you the line you want. The simplest way would be to just write:

```
String fileread = "chlist\\GATHER.txt";
    try {                                         
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileread));
        br.readLine();
        String gatherText = br.readLine();
        br.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {}
```

Although you should also consider what you would do if the file does not contain two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and you can get the file datas by each line

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
using apache-common-io utils

```
try
{
    List<String> stringList = FileUtils.readLines(new File("chlist\\GATHER.txt"));
    for (String string : stringList)
    {
        System.out.println("Line String : " + string);
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest external libraries, at least specify what they are and where to get them.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping a counter:

```
final int linesToSkip = 1;
for(int i=0; i<linesToSkip; i++) br.readLine();
String gatherText = br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String fileread = "chlist\\GATHER.txt";
try {                                         
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileread));
String gatherText;
int counter = 0;
while((gatherText = br.readLine()) != null) {
  if(counter ++ == 1) {
    // This is the line you wanted in your example
    System.out.println(gatherText);
  }
}
br.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Apache Commons IO
```

and then following code

```
 String line = FileUtils.readLines(file).get(2);
```