# How can I get a specific line from a text file?

Tags: java, formatting

I don't know how to get a specific line of text from a file. Let's say the text file is:

```
(1) john
(2) mark
(3) Luke
```

How can I get the second line of the text file (mark)? I just need to read it, not to edit it.

Comment: this was already answered a couple of times: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312756/in-java-how-to-read-from-a-file-a-specific-line-given-the-line-number) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138390/read-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file)

Comment: @Stk, are you trying to get the line containing "mark" or just the second line?

Comment: im trying to get a line number like the second line containing mark. im not looking for the person, just wanting to print out what is written on a specific line number. so if i want to see whats on line 2, i would input 2 and it will print out mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n = 2;
String lineN = Files.lines(Paths.get("yourFile.txt"))
                    .skip(n)
                    .findFirst()
                    .get();
```

For pre-Java 8, you could do for instance

```
int n = 2;
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) // Discard n-1 lines
    s.nextLine();
String lineN = s.nextLine();
```

Comment: what is the "lines" for ?

Comment: `lines(...)` is used to get a stream of lines (useful since you're interested in the second *line*) from the given file.

Comment: i know what to put for yourfile but do i have to change files, line and paths to match what i have?

Comment: No, you only need to change `"yourFile.txt"` to the path of your file. If you're using a relative path, beware of your current working directory.

Comment: lines is having a problem because java is saying that the method lines is undfined for the type files

Comment: Make sure you use capital `F` in `Files` and that you have imported `java.nio.file.Files`.

Comment: i did. it still has problems

Comment: Make sure you have the latest Java version (Java 8).

Comment: and if i don't that won't work?

Comment: Try my pre-Java 8 solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to read a specific line without reading previous lines first. You could loop x number of times until you reach the line you desire.

For example:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("myfile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
int lineNum = 2; //line of file to read
for(int i = 1; i < lineNum; i++)
     br.readLine();
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apache [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class

```
File file = new File("file_name.txt");
String encoding = null; // default to platform
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(file, encoding);
String line2 = lines.get(1);
```

Comment: It seems that `findInLine` scans only current line, so it will fail if `mark` is not in first line.