# what are different ways to read specific lines from text file in java?

Tags: java

I am new baby in Java Programming, i want to know what is efficient way to read specific line from text file in java?

Comment: This question is already in other threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138390/reading-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file-in-java

Comment: That question is tagged `apache-commons-io`, this one isn't. I'm sure there are earlier versions of this question (several of them), but that's not a good close-target (and my bad for not checking better before closing).

Answer (score 0):

Use this but it has less efficiency!

```
String line = FileUtils.readLines(file).get(lineNumber);
```

If your files's lines has same size and you want to read line 15.

```
RandomAccessFile random=new RandomAccessFile("filename","r");
//let say Your line size if a;
random.seek(a*14);
random.readLine();
```

Use this if you don't have same size and let say you wanna read 15th line

```
BufferedReader random=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
            int counter=0;
              while((line=random.readLine())!=null){
                  counter++;
                  if(counter==15){
                      //do whatever
                  }
              }
```

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder I didn't copy anyone's answer.

Comment: Apologies, I took this for a copy of [Bozho's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2138411/157247).